# UIActionSheet with UIPickerView and Done, Next, Previous buttons

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet

i am trying to implement an action sheet that contains a picker view and a segmented control bar with a previous button, next button and done button like the image as follows https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX61b.jpg. I currently am able to make it look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpljb.jpg.  I was wondering if someone could help me get the picker view to sit on the bottom and just make it look a little better.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're targeting very old versions of iOS (i.e. versions earlier than 3.2), the best way to do it is to take a completely different approach.

As of 3.2, any UIResponder (which includes all UIViews) can return a UIView from its `inputView` property to show that view instead of the keyboard when the view becomes the first responder. This even works for views that normally don't become first responder or don't display the keyboard at all. It's simple:

1. Design your popup view, as you would any other view.
2. Ensure that your widget view returns YES from `canBecomeFirstResponder`.
3. Ensure that your widget view returns an instance of your popup view from `inputView`.

More details are available in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1).

Also, BTW, if you're on an iPad you should probably use a UIPopoverController to display a UIPickerView instead of either of these methods. Apple [may actually require this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW23) if you intend to get your app in the app store.

Comment: thanks for the heads up.  i knew that there must have been something weird with the way i was doing it but is there any tutorials on how to do this or can you provide any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The next and previous buttons are actually showing your images to segmentedController Within a toolbar. To get it You have to define the segmentedController and UIToolbar on. H. Next add the DataSource and UIPickerView 
Then in the viewDidLoad create objects and define Their properties. For example:

```
 if (keyboardToolbar == nil) {
        keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        [keyboardToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];


        segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Anterior", @"Siguiente", nil]];
        [segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
        [segControl setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        segControl.frame = CGRectMake(5, 7, 150, 33);
        segControl.momentary = YES;
        [segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *aceptar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hecho" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cerrarTeclado:)];

        //aceptar.width = 70.0f;

        [keyboardToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: extraSpace, aceptar, nil]];
        [keyboardToolbar addSubview:segControl];
    }
```